# Ubercart shipping per country

Tags: drupal, conditional-statements, ubercart

I don't want to use the UPS shipping, I have a list of prices per country that my client wanted adding. Now I have been told to do this via conditional actions but I haven't got the vaguest idea how I would set this up, none of the options seem to allow me to set up specific values per country. Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "prices per country" do you mean a flat rate per country?

If so, create a flat rate price for each country (admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/flatrate).  Example: `International - Canada Flat rate`

This will also add triggers for each flat rate you create in the conditional actions: (admin/store/ca). Example: `Trigger: Getting shipping quote via International - Canada`

Edit the trigger and click the "conditions" tab.  Under "Available conditionns" select "check an order's shipping country".  Click the "add condition" button.  Then select the country (example: canada) and save the page.

(this is for drupal 6 & ubercart 2)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it. In fact I had already worked it out for myself but it would not alow me to anwer my own question because I am new. I appreciate u taking the time to answer tho so ill give u best answer. Thanks